# how to slice and assign in tensorflow2.0

Tags: tensorflow

I find it annoyed with slice and assign in tf2.0. Supposing array is a 2D array. In numpy, I can do

```py
array[:, [1, 3]] = a_num - array[:, [3, 1]]
```

But how can i achieve these ops in tf2.0? I want to know.

Comment: It would help if you provide more specific inputs, such as `array` and `a_num`. What's the shapes of them?

Comment: Sorry for the inexplicit expression. array is a 2D array, e.g. np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4)). a_num is a scalar value, e.g. 2.